# Can't change column name in python using pandas library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khJXN.png)

data set

```
                     Age
  Shoes Name    
  Nike Dunks       23.000000
  Nike Jordan      21.666667
```

rename column name function

```
 df4=df3.rename(columns = {'Shoes Name':'catagory_of_shoes','Age': 'avg_age_group'})
 df4.head()
```

output

```
            avg_age_group
Shoes Name  
Nike Dunks     23.000000
Nike Jordan    21.666667
```

It's not changing the 1st column name.

Comment: I also try to apply another function to change the name and shows error (see the above image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.index.name` to access the index name.

```py
df.index.name = 'catagory_of_shoes'
```

Or you can reset the index to column

```py
df4 = (df3.reset_index()
       .rename(columns={'Shoes Name': 'catagory_of_shoes',
                        'Age': 'avg_age_group'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1st column isn't a column, it is the `index`. See `pd.rename` ([link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)) for details of how to rename the index